# Audio conference using jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want a make a setup where each client send their audio stream to a server. Now server mix up different audio stream and broadcast to every client and client play that sound. I tried webrtc to grab the microphone now I faced the problem how I send the data to server. Some how websocket send the blob to the server I got another issue how I mix them up and maintain synchronization. I am planing to do this using java. Most importantly I have to store the entire audio communication to server for later use.

Comment: What is the question?  Where is the code?

Comment: What you have tried till now ?

Comment: well I need a concept. I am going through several website. In don't  get much. I got a solution about media server but that one is expensive on the context I am working on. If I got a direction then I can start working on that.